# Powershell Change User

Tags: powershell

I'm creating a function to use in my Powershell Profile that will allow me to change users. Below is what I have:

```
function switch-user {

Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [ValidateSet("adminUser","normalUser")]
    $User="normalUser"
)

$Account1 = "$env:USERDOMAIN\normalUser"
$Account2 = "$env:USERDOMAIN\adminUser"
$AccountPassword = Read-Host -AsSecureString

switch($User) {
    'normalUser'    {$username = $Account1 ; $pw = $AccountPassword}
    'adminUser'    {$username = $Account2 ; $pw = $AccountPassword}
}

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
New-PSSession -Credential $cred | Enter-PSSession

}
```

When running the function (i.e. switch-user adminUser), I receive the following error:

```
Param : The term 'Param' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At C:\Users\normalUser\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1:7 char:5
+     Param(
+     ~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Param:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

I'm fairly new to Powershell. Am I incorrectly declaring the Param? I know it needs to be the first line in a function, so what am I missing?

Comment: Sounds like an encoding issue ? Your function works fine on my computer, tho not related to the error but the `switch` should be something like `$username = switch($User) { 'normalUser' {$Account1} ; 'adminUser' {$Account2} }` and there is no need to do `$pw = $AccountPassword`.

Comment: I believe you're correct. Issue seems to be that I had the profile file open in VSCode when I was trying to run it at the same time in PowerShell. Closing the file resolved this issue.